# Laravel rating data save with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I try to save data of post rating with ajax in laravel 5.5

here is my form:

```
 <form class="foodstars" action="{{route('foodStar')}}" id="addStar" method="POST">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
         <input class="star star-5" value="5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
         <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
         <input class="star star-4" value="4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
         <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
         <input class="star star-3" value="3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
         <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
         <input class="star star-2" value="2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
         <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
         <input class="star star-1" value="1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
         <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
   </form>
```

Here is my Ajax:

```
<script>
$('#addStar').onclick('.foodstars',function(e) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/',
        data: $('#addStar').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },

    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function foodStar(){
        // $rating = new Rating;
        // $rating->rating = 4;
        // $rating->user_id = \Auth::id();
        // $food->ratings()->save($rating);
        $rating = new Rating;
        $rating->user_id = \Auth::id();
        $rating->rating = //get new star count;
        $food->ratings()->save($rating);
        return response()->json(['rating' => $rating->rating]);
    }
```

and here is my route:

```
Route::post('/rating', 'FrontendController@foodStar')->name('foodStar');
```

Default code of my package provided static way to save rates but i need to get what user will select, sample code of package is commented in my controller code.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $foodId }}">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#addStar').change('.star', function(e) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Controller:

```
namespace ...
...
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...

public function foodStar (Request $request) {
    // $rating = new Rating;
    // $rating->rating = 4;
    // $rating->user_id = \Auth::id();
    // $food->ratings()->save($rating);
    $rating = new Rating;
    $rating->user_id = \Auth::id();
    $rating->rating = $request->input('star');
    $food = Food::find($request->input('id'));
    $food->ratings()->save($rating);
    return response()->json(['rating' => $rating->rating]);
}
```

Comment: Not saving data.

Comment: @mafortis If you do a `dd($request->input('star'))` does it show the rating value? What's the output of `dd($rating)` after you assign the request value?

Comment: if i use `dd($request->input('star'))` getting error of loading page, if i use `dd($rating)` or `dd($rating->rating);` nothing will happen.

Comment: I think is not process saving to want return any dd.

Comment: @mafortis What about `return $request->input('star');` and then `return $rating;`? Can't try myself right now.

Comment: No! still nothing saves!

Comment: @mafortis I know that, but do you get any output in your javascript console?

Comment: No nothing, console empty, view not change etc.

Comment: @mafortis Remove your javascript code, add a submit button in your form and try what I suggest in my first comment. The problem probably has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: Ok now i'm getting error of $food not recognized and I added this `$food = Food::find($id);` and in function `foodStar (Request $request, $id)` but i get error of `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::foodStar(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: @mafortis Add the Food ID as an input in your form (don't know where are you getting from) `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $foodId }}">` and `Food::find($request->input('id'))`.

Comment: Now working :) but is there a way to remove this button?

Comment: @mafortis Glad it works. Yes, just add again the javascript code and remove the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155562/discussion-between-mafortis-and-azeos).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is  very simple.

Change `data: $('#addStar').serialize(),` to `data: {rating: $('input:checked').val()},`

And for the server side

```
public function foodStar(Request $request){
        // $rating = new Rating;
        // $rating->rating = 4;
        // $rating->user_id = \Auth::id();
        // $food->ratings()->save($rating);
        $rating = new Rating;
        $rating->user_id = \Auth::id();
        $rating->rating = $request->rating; //get new star count;
        $food->ratings()->save($rating);
        return response()->json(['rating' => $rating->rating]);
    }
```

You should also change the url in your ajax

Comment: still nothing happeed.

Comment: change url to what? rating is in posts and each post has different url.

Comment: @mafortis I edit the answer. And you need change the url to '/rating' instead of '/'

Comment: I did your changes still nothing saves

Comment: @mafortis You can try  `dd($request->all())` to see if the request contains the value